# Serialize MySQL relationship data inside of a query

Tags: mysql

My app has **Documents** and **Document Categories** in a many-to-many relationship. Three standard tables...

```
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` int(10),
  `name` varchar(255)
) 

CREATE TABLE `document_document_category` (
  `id` int(10),
  `document_id` int(10),
  `document_category_id` int(10),
)

CREATE TABLE `document_categories` (
  `id` int(10),
  `name` varchar(255),
)
```

I want to write one single query that dumps all document data into a single row. For the document categories, I want it to be serialized to comma separated values. So if the document table had one file named `report.pdf` and it was assigned two categories, `Report` and `Finance`, the query would return the following:

```
--------------------------------------
| Name          | Categories         |
--------------------------------------
| report.pdf    | Report, Finance    |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.name, group_concat(c.name)
from documents d
join document_document_category dc on dc.document_id = d.id
join document_categories c on dc.document_category_id = c.id
group by d.name
```

`group_concat` has some options to define the delimiter and ordering the list ...

Comment: Too easy. Thanks!